# No retorna respuesta usando Http de fluter

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy intentando consumir una API de paises, usando el paquete http de flutter pero no me responde nada ni me imprime lo que sigue el codigo debajo, tampoco veo que lo capture en el catch.

```
     Future getCountryByName(String name) async {
    try {
      print(name);

      final url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/colombia';
      var response = await http.get(url);
      print(response);
      return [];
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Lo estoy usando en el metodo buildResults, del SearchDegelate

```
Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
if (query.trim().length == 0) {
  return Text('No hay valor');
}

final countryService = new CountryService();
return FutureBuilder(
    future: countryService.getCountryByName(query),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Country> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
          snapshot.hasData) {
        return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
      } else
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
    });
```

}

Solo me imprime el `print(name)`.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes agregar como estás llamando a ese método? también, lo estás probando en simulador? android, ios ? debug, release?

Comment: Hola, edite la pregunte estoy tratando de hacer un searchDegelate, estoy usando el emulador.

Comment: antes de llamar a final countryService = new CountryService(); , puedes hacer un print? para ver si entra a un bucle infinito ?

Comment: Ok, ahora lo intento

Comment: imprimio una vez , y luego salio esto: F/crash_dump32(13872): crash_dump.cpp:398] failed to get process threads: No such file or directory

Comment: parece como si hubiera un bucle infinito -> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchDelegate/buildResults.html   ,  yo no usaría ese search delegate y crearía mi propia página/widget de búsqueda

Comment: Puede ser alguna configuracion con la red?, estaba intentando obtener una img, pero no me la trae , pero tampoco me bota un error.

Comment: probaste llamar a ese servicio no en el searchdelegate sino en un widget comun?

Comment: Hola, creo que fue tema del dispositivo virtual que estaba usando. Cree uno nuevo y me funciona normal. Pero no entiendo por que el que estaba usando ya no funcionaba